# Is it ok to launch jobs from an @OnApplicationStart job?

Tags: playframework, jobs

From such a job, I'm doing:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {
  Foo foo = new Job<Foo>() {
    ...
    return new Foo();
  }.now().get();
}
```

And I find that the inner job is never executed, bringing the application to a deadlock, because it blocks on the `get()`.

I'm running Play 1.2.4 in Dev Mode. The job is submitted to `JobsPlugins.executor`, which is initialized to have 10 threads - more than enough. I tried putting a breakpoint in the Callable inside `Job.now()` - that breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: why do you have a job within a job? Why not just have two jobs annotated with @onapplicationstart

Comment: @Codemwnci - I'm trying to reuse a piece of code that is already written as a job and used elsewhere. As a workaround, I extracted the common logic to a normal method instead of a job, so I got this working - still, I'd like to know if calling a job from another job, specifically on startup, is supported, or if not, why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is supported and works well. One of the reason to do this could be to control the order of jobs execution.

For my App, only **BootstrapJob** is annotated with **@OnApplicationStart** and controls the order of execution

```
public void doJob() {

    if (User.count() == 0)
        Fixtures.loadModels("user-data.yml");

    Logger.info("Starting synchronous jobs.");
    new StaticDataJob().doJob();

    Logger.info("Starting asynchronous jobs.");
    new TransactionJob().now();
    new ReportJob().now();

        Logger.info("Boostrap job complete.");
}
```

Comment: If you add `.get()` after calling the jobs, do you get the same hanging that I'm experiencing ? I understand I can call doJob() to skip the whole asynch issue, just wondering.